# Cannot access header or business process flow controls on a CRM form

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

For some strange reason I cannot access any control on the header or the business process flow section. I try to access them in the debugging tool after the page has loaded but I get null all the time. This is what I have/have done so far:

- CRM 2016 on-premise
- I have administrator rights
- I use Xrm.Page.getControl("header_CONTROL NAME") for header controls
- I use Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_CONTROL NAME") for BPF controls
- I have checked the control names and they are correct

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the record exist, or are you trying it in a "New Record" form ?

Comment: Sorry I missed your question. Yes, the record exists.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you are in a wrong context in your debugging tool because forms usually rendered in an iframe.

If by that tool you mean the Chrome DevTools try to select some of those controls in elements view of your DOM and execute Xrm.Page.getControl after that.

Comment: Hi Konstantin. By the debugging tool I mean the F12 debugging tool as part of Chrome or IE. I can select those elements in the debugging tool after the page loaded and I can see the element IDs but executing Xrm.Page.getControl() using those IDs always returns null. However, the same code works fine on page load when I attach the JS code to the form properties. I just don't understand why I cannot access the elements in the debugging tool. Other people must have seen this issue as well. It's easy to test.

Comment: What I suspect is that you are executing your calls in a different from the form javascript scope. Google Chrome is smart enough to switch the context when you are selecting some element in the debugging tool. So what I suggest you is to firstly select the element containing your control, and then execute Xrm call in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happen when I tried accessing the controls in a "New Record" (create) form. In Update forms the same code worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. However, I am debugging an existing record so it's not a new form.